# Django Project Questions

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have mac with frontend (react JS based) and backend (Django based). I am seeing error saying,

`null value in column "customer_id" of relation "main_order" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (58, 2023-07-20 09:32:15.565247+00, null).`

Following are the code details:

views.py

```
class OrdersList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OrderSerializer

    **def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST)
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)**

class OrderDetails(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.OrderItems.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OrderDetailsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        order_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        order = models.Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
        order_items=models.OrderItems.objects.filter(order=order)
        return order_items
```

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer_orders')
    order_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.order_time)

class OrderItems(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

serializers.py

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Order
        fields = ['id', 'customer']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Meta.depth = 1
```

I am printing the request in post function of OrderList view class and I see

```
<QueryDict: {'customer': ['7']}>
<QueryDict: {'customer': ['7']}>
```

I am seeing following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/orders/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/cursor.py", line 723, in execute
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
psycopg.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "customer_id" of relation "main_order" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (64, 2023-07-20 10:37:10.07752+00, null).

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/burteanupamnarayan/DistributedRepo2023/project/main/views.py", line 138, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 242, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 658, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 814, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 877, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1020, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1061, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1805, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1820, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/cursor.py", line 723, in execute
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
```

I tried to follow the request from frontend (reactJs based) to django model but couldn't follow it beyond the view class

Request Payload:

```
-----------------------------7872495127917832492110041678
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customer"

7
-----------------------------7872495127917832492110041678--
```

Error response,
`null value in column "customer_id" of relation "main_order" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (58, 2023-07-20 09:32:15.565247+00, null).`

Comment: Could you also share your request payload?

Comment: Updated the question. The request payload is: 

`-----------------------------7872495127917832492110041678 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customer"


7
-----------------------------7872495127917832492110041678--`

Comment: It seems that you have a database register at row 58 that breaks the relationship between "customer_id" and "main_order". Do you have a `main_order` field or table? Could you print it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your OrderSerializer like this!

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'customer', 'order_time']
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As order is related with customer, so try updating OrderSerializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
     model = Order
     fields = ['id', 'customer', 'order_time']
    
customer = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
queryset = Customer.objects.all())
```

---

**Or**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
     model = Order
     fields = ['id', 'customer_id', 'order_time']
    
customer_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
```

And validate whether customer with the incoming id exits or not, by overriding validate method in serializer class.